# "Interpolation Order -> 2" resulting in nonsensical fits

Tags: plotting, interpolation, data

I've been running into some strange behaviour with InterpolationOrder in some of my plots recently.

Consider the following MWE (that zooms in around the problem area):

```
MyData = {{0.9, 34.00345}, {1., 33.67193}, {1.2, 33.30703}, {1.5, 33.18968}, {2., 33.18565}, {10., 33.22217}};
ListPlot[MyData, PlotRange -> {{0.9, 2.1}, {33.175, 33.31}}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

The output plot has a loop in it, the result isn't even a function that passes the vertical line test.

[image: Unintended Behaviour]

However, if you omit the last data point, it works as expected.

```
ListPlot[MyData[[1 ;; 5]], PlotRange -> {{0.9, 2}, {33.15, 33.25}}, Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

[image: Intended Behaviour]

I've run into this issue a few times over the last few months with different datasets.

I've tried using `Interpolation[..., Method->"Spline"]` but that comes with its own problems like overfitting.

Does anybody know what causes it or how to fix it?

Comment: The `ListPlot` output is similar, but not identical with, `ParametricPlot[{Interpolation[MyData[[All, 1]], t, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 2, Method -> "Spline"], 
  Interpolation[MyData[[All, 2]], t, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
   Method -> "Spline"]}, {t, 1, 5.5}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.9, 2.1}, {33.175, 33.31}}, AspectRatio -> 0.61]`

Answer (score 3):

- Compare with `Interpolation`.

```
MyData = {{0.9, 34.00345}, {1., 33.67193}, {1.2, 33.30703}, {1.5, 
    33.18968}, {2., 33.18565}, {10., 33.22217}};
Plot[Interpolation[MyData, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
   Method -> "Spline"]@t, {t, Min[MyData[[;; , 1]]], 
  Max[MyData[[;; , 1]]]}, Epilog -> {Red, Point[MyData]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

- Compare with `BSplineFunction`.

```
MyData = {{0.9, 34.00345}, {1., 33.67193}, {1.2, 33.30703}, {1.5, 
    33.18968}, {2., 33.18565}, {10., 33.22217}};
(* Graphics[BSplineCurve[MyData],PlotRange->All,AspectRatio->1/GoldenRatio] *)
ParametricPlot[BSplineFunction[MyData]@t, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All,
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Epilog -> {Point[MyData]}]
```

[image]

- Compare with `MaxPlotPoints -> 4`.

```
MyData = {{0.9, 34.00345}, {1., 33.67193}, {1.2, 33.30703}, {1.5, 
    33.18968}, {2., 33.18565}, {10., 33.22217}};
ListPlot[MyData, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> Full, Joined -> True, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 2, MaxPlotPoints -> 4]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting comparisons, but I'm still not sure why this behaviour is happening or how to prevent it (aside from just not using `Joined->True, InterpolationOrder->2` going forward. 

@Michael E2 pointed out that, interestingly, it's behaving similar to Parametric Plot. Is this intended behaviour?

Is there no way to fix it aside from bringing in various spline functions and toying with them until something behaves like I would assume the system should?

Also, is this intended behaviour or have I come across a bug that should be reported?

Comment: @Kvo  Yes, `ListPlot` draw a parametric curve, it is not always be a function. `Interpolation` always draw a function.